# Does an invertible matrix has a basis for its nullspace or is it empty?

Tags: linear-algebra

Since in invertible matrices

$$
rank=r=m=n
$$

The matrix is both a square matrix and invertible from both left and right sides, left side inverse B and right side inverse C

$$
C=B=A^{-1}
$$

We end up with this equality. So when looked at the nullspace of this matrix A the only solution is zero(0) but which statement do we say

1)there is no solution

or

2)the basis is zero

3)The nullspace is empty

Comment: The nullspace is $\{0\}$. Hence a _basis for_ the nullspace if $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the matrix $A$ is invertible, we say that there is no **nontrivial** solution to the equation $Ax = 0$. There is always the trivial solution $x = 0$, so the adjective "nontrivial" is necessary. If you say "there is no solution", people will often understand what you mean, but formally it will be wrong.

Similarly, the nullspace is not empty: it contains $0$, like all vector spaces (don't forget that a vector space is *never* empty!). You can say that the nullspace is trivial, $\ker A = \{0\}$.

However, in this case the only basis of the nullspace is the empty set, not "zero" (a set can't be "zero"). So you can say without problem that the basis of the nullspace is empty, $\mathscr{B} = \varnothing$. All three of these assertions are equivalent, so you can say whichever one you prefer.

Comment: More important imo than zero not being a set is the fact that $0$ cannot be an element of a basis.

Comment: Great explanation thanks!